# The ratio of spectral edge of the GOE matrix

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices

Consider a $n\times n$ GOE random matrix. If we assume that $|\lambda_1|>|\lambda_2|\ge \dots \ge |\lambda_n|$, can we get the order of $｜\lambda_1｜/｜\lambda_2｜$ or even $\lambda_1/\lambda_2$?

Any reference are appreciate!

---

If we change the condition that $\lambda_1>\lambda_2\ge \dots \ge \lambda_n$, then by $\lambda_1-\lambda_2=O_p(n^{2/3})$ (this result follows from the limiting joint distribution of spectral edge is Tracy-Windom law), can  we have that
$$
\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2}=1+O_P(n^{2/3})?
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|\lambda_1|=2+\delta_1$, $|\lambda_2|=2+\delta_2$, with $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ both of order $n^{-2/3}$, so
$$|\lambda_1|/|\lambda_2|=1+(\delta_1-\delta_2)/2+{\cal O}(n^{-4/3})=1+{\cal O}(n^{-2/3}).$$

Since you do not know the sign of $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, the ratio $\lambda_1/\lambda_2$ without the absolute value signs is undetermined: it could be close to $+1$ or close to $-1$.

Comment: Thank you! But can I ask that how to get the first equality? $(2+\delta_1)/(2+\delta_2)=1+(\delta_1-\delta_2)/(2+\delta_2)$. I am stuck on there.

Comment: $(2+\delta_1)/(2+\delta_2)=(1+\delta_1/2)[1-\delta_2/2+{\cal O}(\delta_2^2)]=1+\delta_1/2-\delta_2/2+{\cal O}(\delta_2^2)+{\cal O}(\delta_1\delta_2)$ $=1+(\delta_1-\delta_2)/2+{\cal O}(n^{-3})$

Comment: Thanks. Also, is not it  $$\lim_{N\to \infty}P(N^{2/3}(\lambda_1-2, \lambda_2-2,\dots, \lambda_N-2)\le x)\to F_2(x)$$? So it seems that $|\lambda_1|-2=O_p(n^{-2/3})$?

Comment: certainly, that is the Tracy-Widom law; the level spacing near the edge decays with $n$ more slowly than in the bulk, as $n^{-2/3}$ instead of as $n^{-1}$.

Comment: So there is a typo in your first line? You wrote the order of $\delta$ is $n^{-3/2}$ but not $n^{-2/3}$.

Comment: yes, I got the power upside down: 2/3 not 3/2 --- thanks for correcting me.

Comment: Dose this result hold for $|\lambda_1|/|\lambda_k|$ for a fixed number $k$ which is less than $n$?

Comment: yes it does, since for $n\rightarrow\infty$ the number $k$ will then be much less than $n$.