# Can we still have the order of ratio result of the two smallest eigenvalues?

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices

For GOE matrix $A$, we have the following limiting distribution for eigenvalues  of $A$ by $\lambda_N\ge \lambda_{N-1}\ge \dots \ge \lambda_1$:

> In this [paper][1], if we denote the $k$ largest eigenvalues by $\lambda_N,\lambda_{n-1},··· ,\lambda_{N-k+1}, $ then for Gaussian ensembles the joint distribution function of rescaled eigenvalues has the limit:
> $$
> \lim_{N\to\infty}P(N^{2/3}(\lambda_N-2)\le s_1,\dots, N^{2/3}(\lambda_{N-k+1}-2)\le s_k)=F_{\beta, k}(s_1,\dots, s_k)
> $$

Now, if we can order the eigenvalues of $A$ by $|\sigma_N|\ge |\sigma_{N-1}|\ge \dots \ge|\sigma_{1}|$, can we still have the similar results as in [The ratio of spectral edge of the GOE matrix](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434446/the-ratio-of-spectral-edge-of-the-goe-matrix)?

> *[For my notation $\sigma$:  For example, the eigenvalues could be the case $1.98>1.1>...>-1.99>-2$ (where I take $\lambda_N=1.98$, $\lambda_{N-1}=1.1$ and $\lambda_2=-1.99$, $\lambda_1=-2$). Also, we order the eigenvalues by the absolute value: it becomes $|\lambda_1|>|\lambda_2|>|\lambda_N|>....$. So the order changed. I denoted the new notation for $\sigma_N=\lambda_1, \sigma_{N-1}=\lambda_2, \sigma_{N-3}=\lambda_N$.]*

That is
$$
\frac{|\sigma_{2}|}{|\sigma_{1}|}=1+O(N^{-2/3})
$$

---

To prove the result in the above question, we need the joint limiting distribution also hold for $|\sigma_{1}|$ and $|\sigma_{2}|$. Do we still have $$|\sigma_{2}|-|\sigma_{1}|=O(N^{-2/3})?$$

Comment: $\sigma$ is the real part of $\lambda$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson No. I mean if we order the eigenvalues of matrix $A$. Then the order will be changed after I take the absolute value. All eigenvalues are real.

Comment: Then I don't understand what $\sigma$ is. Some permutation of $\{1,2,\dots,N\}$? Please edit the body of your question, to clarify.

Comment: @GerryMyerson For example, the eigenvalues could be the case $1.98>1.1>...>-1.99>-2$ (where I take $\lambda_N=1.98$, $\lambda_{N-1}=1.1$ and $\lambda_2=-1.99$, $\lambda_1=-2$). Also, we order the eigenvalues by the absolute value: it becomes $|\lambda_1|>|\lambda_2|>|\lambda_N|>....$. So the order changed. I denoted the new notation for $\sigma_N=\lambda_1, \sigma_{N-1}=\lambda_2, \sigma_{N-3}=\lambda_N$. Is it clear now?

Comment: Why $\sigma_{N-3}=\lambda_N$? Did you mean $\sigma_{N-2}=\lambda_N$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, that is a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\sigma_i$'s are a permutation of the $\lambda_i\in(-2,2)$, ordered by absolute value in the order $|\sigma_N|\geq|\sigma_{N-1}|\geq \cdots\geq|\sigma_1|$. So $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ are the eigenvalues closest to zero (in the bulk of the spectrum), while $\sigma_N$ and $\sigma_{N-1}$ are the eigenvalues closest to $\pm 2$ (near the spectral edge). One has $|\sigma_1|,|\sigma_2|={\cal O}(N^{-1})$ in view of the Wigner semicircle, while $|\sigma_N|,|\sigma_{N-1}|=2+{\cal O}(N^{-2/3})$, in view of the Tracy-Widom law, hence

$$|\sigma_2|-|\sigma_1|={\cal O}(N^{-1}),$$
$$|\sigma_N|-|\sigma_{N-1}|={\cal O}(N^{-2/3}).$$

(The OP has this the other way around, perhaps a typo?)

Comment: Thanks! So what is the ratio of $|\sigma_N|/|\sigma_l|$ for a fixed number $l$? Is it still same as the answer in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434446/the-ratio-of-spectral-edge-of-the-goe-matrix?

Comment: Also, for the top eigenvalues, can we say $|\sigma_N|-|\sigma_{l}|=O(N^{-2/3})$ for a fixed number $l$? We need this one to get the ratio of these two eigenvalues.

Comment: first question: for a fixed number $l$ and $N\rightarrow\infty$ you have $|\sigma_N|=2+{\cal O}(N^{-2/3})$ and $|\sigma_l|={\cal O}(N^{-1})$, so $|\sigma_N|/|\sigma_l|={\cal O}(N)$.

Comment: second question: $|\sigma_N|-|\sigma_l|=2+{\cal O}(N^{-2/3})$; this is not what you wrote, you need to keep in mind that $\sigma_N$ will be near $\pm 2$ while $\sigma_l$ will be near 0 for large $N$ and fixed $l$.

Comment: Thank you! So will this result be different from the result under normal sorting? For $\lambda_N\ge \lambda_{N-1}\ge ...\ge \lambda_1$, we can say for a fixed number $l$ that $\lambda_N/\lambda_l=1+O(N^{-2/3})$ by the similar result in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434446/the-ratio-of-spectral-edge-of-the-goe-matrix.

Comment: Sorry, can I ask why $|\sigma_l|$ will be $O(N^{-1})$ but not $2+O(N^{-2/3})$? This is different from the Tracy-Widom law.

Comment: you have sorted the eigenvalues in absolute value; $|\sigma_l|$ with $l\ll N$ is one of the smallest eigenvalues in absolute value, so it differs from zero by order $l$ times the level spacing in the bulk, which is $1/N$, so $|\sigma_l|={\cal O}(N^{-1})$; the difference in the order of $\lambda_l$ and $\sigma_l$ is that you have sorted the latter in absolute value.